# Allowing public access to only 1 endpoint of Azure Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm building a small Azure Serverless Application with 3 distinct functions triggered by 3 different HTTP events. I set the "Authorization Level" to "Anonymous" for each of the functions. Then I set up the Authentication (on the application level) to link to my Azure Active Directory. Although it took me some time to figure out that part, in the end it appears to work like a charm. The issue is that right now I'm required to pass the bearer token for each and every one of these functions, whereas I need one of them to be publicly accessible.
Is there any way to do that that does not require me to split that one function into a separate Azure Application?

Answer (score 1):

I think URL authorization rules should help here.

For your scenario, Enable the Authentication/Authorization and allow anonymous access in the portal. Next, you'll want to create an `authorization.json` file in the root of your site and define two routes:

- Disable anonymous access at the root.
- Enable anonymous access for the anonymous function URL.

**authorization.json**

```
{
  "routes": [{
      "path_prefix": "/",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "RedirectToLoginPage" }
    },{
      "path_prefix": "/api/HttpTrigger1",
      "policies": { "unauthenticated_action": "AllowAnonymous" }
    }]
}
```

[image]
[image]

**NOTE:** Make sure to Stop/Start Function App after enabling the Authentication/Authorization and adding the authorization.json file at wwwroot folder.

Comment: when I have the authorization.json file included in my distribution I get an error when my Azure build loads the function website? "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: I experience the same issue. Letting some functions be anonymous must be a common scenario. I don't know why they haven't thought of an official way to do this! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you implemented the app level security but in a regular OWIN or CORE app, the token handler will just pass the request as unauthenticated to the controller method if it does not find a valid token in the Authorization header (no header or token invalid). It's up to the method then to decide whether to handle the request or reject as unauthorized. Can you change your token verifier accordingly? (In fact, if your API can receive tokens issued by different issuers - AAD, B2C, Ping - you can configure several token handlers, each will try to va

Comment: token verifier? I never configured the token verifier.
I went to <Function app> ->"Platform Features"-> "Authentication/Authorization" and specified "Action to take when request is not authenticated: Log in with Azure Active Directory" and then pointed the ADD Authentication Provider to my AAD, which already has 1 user and client credentials configured.
No authentication ever happens inside my code. Everything is handled by Azure. If the Authorization header is missing or invalid, my Azure Function will never be triggered in any way

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your 'on the application level' - presuming you did it in code rather than in the service ('EasyAuth'). I don't believe there is a way to bypass that validation: it's either on for all functions or off for all functions. In code you would use something like JWTTokenHandler class and do your own validation (only in the functions where you need it).